# How to pass the value of input to another input on the same row

Tags: jquery

I have a textbox qty and textbox unit_price in a row. Now I want to pass the value of qty to unit_price. I was able to get the value of qty but I cant pass the value to its to unit_price row, instead it passes the qty value to each unit_price's rows.

HTML:

```
<table class="data">
<tr>
    <td><input="text" class="qty" name="qty[]"></td><td><input="text" class="unit_price" name="unit_price[]"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
   <td><input="text" class="qty" name="qty[]"></td><td><input="text" class="unit_price" name="unit_price[]">
   </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td><input="text" class="qty" name="qty[]"></td><td><input="text" class="unit_price" name="unit_price[]">
    </td>
</tr>
```

Here's my jquery:

```
$('table.data').on('change','.qty',function(){
  var val = $(this).parent().parent().find('input[type=text]').val();
  alert(val);
  $(".unit_price").parent().parent().find('input[type="text"]').val(val);
})
```

Need some help on how to pass the value of qty to unit_price.

Comment: Can you give us some HTML?

Comment: yes post your html, so we know how to improve it

Comment: `$(".unit_price").parent().parent().find('input[type="text"]')` finds all text `input`s in **all** `.unit_price`'s grandparents.

Comment: Assuming the classes mentioned are of its corresponding input elements, I think this should solve your problem `$(".unit_price").val($(this).val());`

Comment: I updated my post.

Ok I will try @nikhil, thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `.closest()` to get to the closest parent instead of `.parent()` twice and make sure to be in the context of the selector with `this`:

```
$('table.data').on('change','.qty',function(){
  var val = $(this).val();
  alert(val);
  $(this).closest('tr').find(".unit_price").val(val);
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that retrieving your unit price is correct.
Find the previous textbox using jquery [prev()](https://api.jquery.com/prev/) function.

```
var unitPriceObj = $(this).parent().parent().find('input[type=text]');
var unitPrice = unitPriceObj .val(); // get unit price value
unitPriceObj.prev('input').val(unitPrice ); // assign it to qty
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you go:

```
$('table.data').on('change','.qty',function() {
  var qtyInput = $(e.target)

  qtyInput.parents("tr").find('.unit_price').val( qtyInput.value );
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Or use .next() method to get the following

```
$('table.data').on('change','.qty',function(){
    $(this).parent().next().find(".unit_price").val($(this).val());
})
```